# Django: return messages in form.clean()

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a CreateView that uses a ModelForm to add a new calendar event. Sometimes, when adding a new calendar event, another calendar event has to be added before the new event to be able to successfully validate the new event (which happens in the ModelForm.clean() method). I think the only place this other event can be added is in the clean method, just before the validation which validates the new event. Am I right that this is the only place I can do this? I want to let the user know that this happened using Django messages, but of course I don't have access to the request object in the ModelForm. That makes me think I have to add this event in another place. Which method of CreateView is suited for this purpose?

I'm sorry in advance for my English and if my question isn't worded good enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use ModelForm, but a custom form, then you have more control over actions. Then you can pass the request to the form and use it during your clean process.

Here is an example of one of my forms where I needed access to request to save form content:

```
class RatifyQuestionForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        ....
        ....

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        # create approval record
        ratification = Ratification.objects.create(
                        assessment=data['assessment'],
                        alternative=data['alternative'],
                        author=request.user)
```

In a similar way you could access self.request in the clean method.

You instantiate the form in your view as so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RatifyQuestionForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

Comment: Good solution! I just want to add that this could also easily be done with a ModelForm

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have access to request object within your form, you can override the `get_form_kwargs` method within the CreateView (This will give access to self.request within in your form's clean method):

```py
class YourViewName(CreateView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
         kwargs = super(YourViewName, self).get_form_kwargs()
         kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
         return kwargs
```

But, for your scenario it is better to do the validations within the form_valid method in your view. If the validation failed, you can set the message and then call form_invalid() to re-render the form with your error message.

```py
class YourViewName(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if not your_check_goes_here():
            messages.error(self.request, _("Form is Invalid"))
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        return super(YourViewName, self).form_valid(form)
```